# How to dynamically change the script src by taking user value from user input?

Tags: javascript, input, dynamic

I'm trying to dynamically change the <script src=oldValue"/> InputValue depends on what user types in input and after submitting page will reload with new <script src=newValue"/>

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="javascript: window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com/print/' + document.getElementById('text').value);" />


<script src="//script.ashx?company=InputValue" async></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example changes the src attribute for the script element. The second example is inserting a new script element. I don't know what would work best in your case.

The first example:

```js
document.forms.test.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var new_script = e.target.script.value;
  var script_elm = document.scripts.customscript;
  script_elm.src = `/script.ashx?company=${new_script}`;
  console.log(script_elm);
});
```

```html
<form name="test">
  <input name="script" type="text" />
  <button>Add script</button>
</form>
<script name="customscript" async></script>
```

The second example:

```js
document.forms.test.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var script_elm = document.createElement('script');
  script_elm.async = true;
  script_elm.innerText = 'function testing(){alert("testing")};';
  document.body.append(script_elm);
  testing();
});
```

```html
<form name="test">
<button>Add script</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for, in my case first example what i needed, Thanks @chrwahl